# SharePoint 2010 SkyDrive Pro sync not working over the internet

Tags: sharepoint-server, azure, onedrive-for-business

I have the following setup:
In Windows Azure I have a Virtual Machine on which a SharePoint Server 2010 is installed. I created a site which is running on port 80. In the azure management website I created an endpoint for port 80 and created an in-bound firewall rule - the site works using a web-browser.

Now I would like to use SkyDrive Pro in order to sync my documents. However, I always get the following error: "We can't find the SharePoint site location. Please check the location address for typing errors."

There are no typing errors. I installed SkyDrive pro on the same virtual machine that SharePoint is on, and voilà it works. It just won't work over the internet. So I am guessing that there is another port I need to open.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: I am having the same issue with Sharepoint 2013 in my office. It would be great if we could get SkyDrive Pro to work over the internet. I don't know if I missed a configuration step or port.

Comment: Hi Christian, I am having the same issue and also think that some port should be opened. Have you found the solution?

Comment: Hi MikhailSP, unfortunately we could not get it to work and are not using SkyDrive and also not SharePoint anymore.